# Which of the following options must be true.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nilpotence

Let $A$ be a $2×2$ non zero matrix with entries in$\Bbb C$ such that $A^2 = 0$. Which of the following statements must be true ?

1. $PAP^{-1}$ is diagonal for some invertible $2×2$ matrix $P$ with entries in $\Bbb R$
2. $A$ has two distinct eigen values in $\Bbb C$
3. $A$ has only one eigen value in $\Bbb C$ with multiplicity $2$
4. $Av = v$ for some $v \in \Bbb C^2, v \neq 0$

My Attempt:
Option 1
If I take $P = I$ then $PAP^{-1} = IAI^{-1} = A$ which is non zero nilpotent matrix and it is not diagonalizable . So $PAP^{-1}$ is not diagonalizable
Hence option 1 is not true.

Option 2,3:
$A$ is nilpotent matrix. So option 3 is true and 2 is false.

Option 4:

Since $A$ is non zero nilpotent matrix. So it is of the form
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0&a_{12}\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ or $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\a_{21}&0\end{pmatrix}$$
Take $v = (\alpha , \beta)^T$ with $v \in \Bbb C^2$ and $\alpha,\beta \neq 0$ and $v \neq 0$
Now $Av = v$ implies $\begin{pmatrix} 0&a_{12}\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha \\ \beta \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}\alpha \\ \beta \end{pmatrix} \implies \begin{pmatrix}a_{12}\beta \\ 0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\alpha \\ \beta \end{pmatrix} \implies \alpha = \beta = 0$
Which is a contradiction as we assumed $\alpha, \beta \neq 0$. So option 4 is false. Please correct me if I'm on wrong track or provide alternate solution if exist.

Comment: For (1), you've shown that $PAP^{-1}$ isn't diagonal for a particular choice of $P$ and $A$. However, in order to negate (1) you need to show that for a particular choice of $A$, the matrix $PAP^{-1}$ isn't diagonal for **any** invertible $P$. You are on the right track though.

Comment: One quick way to handle (2), (3), and (4) simultaneously is to note that $A$'s only eigenvalue is $0$ with [algebraic] multiplicity $2$.

Comment: I think you say that "$Av =v$ for $v \neq 0$ can be written as $Av =1v$. So $1$ is eigen value of $A$ which is not true as $0$ is the only eigen value of $A$"

Comment: Please provide a solution that $PAP^{-1}$ is not diagonalizable in general for particular nilpotent matrix $A$. I have discarded option 1 by taking $P= I$